# How to split a string into only two parts, by the last occurrence of the split char?

Tags: ruby

For example:

```
"Angry Birds 2.4.1".split(" ", 2)
 => ["Angry", "Birds 2.4.1"]
```

How can I split the string into: `["Angry Birds", "2.4.1"]`

Comment: the example is a bit unfortunate because we don't know if the breaking condition is the version number or that you simply want to split on the second ocurrence of a space.

Comment: split on the _last_ occurrence of a space

Answer (score 122, accepted):

[String#rpartition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-rpartition), e.g.

```
irb(main):068:0> str = "Angry Birds 2.4.1"
=> "Angry Birds 2.4.1"
irb(main):069:0> str.rpartition(' ')
=> ["Angry Birds", " ", "2.4.1"]
```

Since the returned value is an array, using *.first* and *.last* would allow to treat the result as if it was split in two, e.g

```
irb(main):073:0> str.rpartition(' ').first
=> "Angry Birds"
irb(main):074:0> str.rpartition(' ').last
=> "2.4.1"
```

Comment: Note that `String#rpartition` plays very nicely with Ruby's _"don't care" variable:

    [1] pry(main)> name, _, version = "Angry Birds 2.4.1".rpartition(' ')
    => ["Angry Birds", " ", "2.4.1"]
    [2] pry(main)> name
    => "Angry Birds"
    [3] pry(main)> version
    => "2.4.1"

So no need for `Array#first` or `Array#last`... less is more!  :-)

Answer (score 11):

I hava a solution like this:

```
class String
  def split_by_last(char=" ")
    pos = self.rindex(char)
    pos != nil ? [self[0...pos], self[pos+1..-1]] : [self]
  end
end

"Angry Birds 2.4.1".split_by_last  #=> ["Angry Birds", "2.4.1"]
"test".split_by_last               #=> ["test"]
```

Comment: rindex is the best and efficient way.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this maybe ?
Split where a space is followed by anything but a space till the end of the string.

```
"Angry Birds 2.4.1".split(/ (?=\S+$)/)
#=> ["Angry Birds", "2.4.1"]
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't seem able to get the example code in my comment properly formatted, so I'm submitting it as a separate answer, even though [Vadym Tyemirov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318367/vadym-tyemirov) deserves all the credit for the `String#rpartition` solution he provided above.

I just wanted to add that `String#rpartition` plays very nicely with Ruby's *"don't care" variable*, as typically you're indeed only interested in the first and last element of the result array, but not the middle element *(the separator)*:

```rb
[1] pry(main)> name, _, version = "Angry Birds 2.4.1".rpartition(' ')
=> ["Angry Birds", " ", "2.4.1"]
[2] pry(main)> name
=> "Angry Birds"
[3] pry(main)> version
=> "2.4.1"
```

So no need for `Array#first` or `Array#last`... less is more!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

`"Angry Birds 2.4.1".split(/ (?=\d+)/)`

Comment: It solves this particular variation of problem, but it is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The rpartition solution makes a great sexy one-liner (I voted for it), but here's another technique if you want a one liner that's more flexible for solving more complex partitioning problems:

```
["Angry Birds 2.4.1".split(' ')[0..-2].join(' '), "Angry Birds 2.4.1".split(' ')[-1..-1].join(' ')]
```

By more flexible, I mean if there were more items being partitioned, you could just adjust the range of the sequence.

Comment: Could you explain why `-2` in `[0..-2]`

Comment: My answer before was incomplete @spuder. I just fixed it. Originally, I was assuming the question didn't care about the second half.

[0..-2] means splice the last element off of the array, because in ruby -1 is the last element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

### Create a `String#split_on_last` method.

***Heavily** inspired by [halfelf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12192707/293280) but permits more than just a single character, doesn't have a default param value and refactored for clarity.*

#### Definition

```rb
class String
  def split_on_last( text )
    position_of_last_occurrence = self.rindex( text )

    return [ self ] if position_of_last_occurrence.nil?

    first_part = self[ 0...position_of_last_occurrence ]
    last_part  = self[ position_of_last_occurrence + text.length..-1 ]

    [ first_part, last_part ]
  end
end
```

#### Usage

```rb
"Angry Birds 2.4.1".split_on_last( " " )
#=> ["Angry Birds", "2.4.1"]

"start middle end end suffix".split_on_last( "end" )
#=> ["start middle end ", " suffix"]

"start middle suffix".split_on_last( "end" ) # No occurrence.
#=> ["start middle suffix"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably way too tricky (and probably not particularly efficient), but you can do this:

```
"Angry Birds 2.4.1".reverse.split(" ", 2).map(&:reverse).reverse
```

Comment: Personally, yours worked out best for me. It's much more readable & deals with excess whitespace.

Comment: Really? `.map(&:reverse).reverse` More readable? :)

Answer (score 1):

reverse, split, then reverse every element and elements in array

```
"Angry Birds 2.4.1".reverse.split(' ', 2).map(&:reverse).reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class String
  def divide_into_two_from_end(separator = ' ')
    self.split(separator)[-1].split().unshift(self.split(separator)[0..-2].join(separator))
  end
end

"Angry Birds 2.4.1".divide_into_two_from_end(' ') #=> ["Angry Birds", "2.4.1"]
```