# How render HTML Link from String with Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert the URL string into an HTML link element (`<a href="#"></a>`) (like Facebook make with his URLs in the text by example)

I tried this solution [Convert links from a string to clickable links using Ruby/Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006016/convert-links-from-a-string-to-clickable-links-using-ruby-rails) but I just get some HTML link in plain text...

Example :

I have this

```
string = "blabla http//www.google.com blabla
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
```

And I would this, not in plain text but as HTML element

```
<p>blabla</p> 
<a href="http//www.google.com">http//www.google.com</a> 
<p>blabla</p>
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`simple_format`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format) view helper method and the [`rails_autolinks`](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) gem that was once part of Rails itself.

Comment: Maybe this will help you:  `URI.extract(string)` https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/URI/extract/class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the plain text can be converted to html by called `html_safe` method on string.
Like `'<a href="http//www.google.com">http//www.google.com</a>'.html_safe`

Comment: Thank you I don't know why it's not working from controller but it's working from view. But I have another question how prevent javascript code like <script>alert('hello')</script> How just passing http url as html_safe ?

Answer (score 0):

I would split the input into "words", compare each word with a regex for a url, and if it matches, wrap it in a link element.

In this answer I'll just use a simple regex. We'll consider anything starting with `http://` or `https://` to be a URL. You can use something more advanced if you like.

```rb
string = "blabla https://www.google.com blabla lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"

string = string.split.map do |word|
  if /https?:\/\/.*/.match word
    next "<a href=\"#{word}\">#{word}</a>"
  else
   next word
  end
end.join(' ')

puts string #=> blabla <a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a> blabla lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

Note that this doesn't actually work with the original string in your answer, because it's not a valid url (it's missing the colon).